# JSF Setter method not working in inputText form

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have the code below. When the user changes the data in the text fields (the correct information shows up, assumably using the getName, getAddress methods etc...) and then hits the save button, the user is taken back to mainPage. If I click on "Edit/View Personal..." and it reloads the editpersonal.xhtml page again, the original values are there, not the changed values. I've checked the headers being sent in chrome and they are being sent so for whatever reason, they are not being set. There exists a get and set method for each of the fields.

I have almost identical code in other pages where I use inputText fields to SET information and it works without issue. I have no idea why this isnt working.

mainPage.xhtml (every function and command on this webpage works)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="userid" value="${CustomBuild.userid}"/>
        #{CustomBuild.getCustomerDetails(userid)}

        <c:set var="configs" value="#{CustomBuild.configs}"/>

        Welcome <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{CustomBuild.name}"/>
        <br></br>
        Please choose from one of the following options below.
        <br></br><br></br>

        <h:form>
                <h:commandButton id="editp" value="View/Edit Personal Information" action="editpersonal" />
                <br></br><br></br>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="#{configs==0}">
                        <h:commandButton id="viewo" value="View Orders" action="vieworders" disabled="true"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="#{configs!=0}">
                        <h:commandButton id="viewo" value="View Orders" action="vieworders" disabled="false"/>
                    </c:when>
                </c:choose>

                <br></br><br></br>
                <h:commandButton id="createo" value="Create New Order" action="createorder" />

        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

editpersonal.xhtml <-- This page doesnt appear to be "saving" the data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputLabel value="Name: " style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText value="#{CustomBuild.name}" />
            <br></br>
            <h:outputLabel value="Address " style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText value="#{CustomBuild.address}" />
            <br></br>
            <h:outputLabel value="Phone Number: " style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText value="#{CustomBuild.phone}" />
            <br></br>
            <h:outputLabel value="Email Address: " style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText value="#{CustomBuild.email}" />
            <br></br>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton id="Save" value="save" action="mainPage" />
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton id="Cancel" value="cancel" action="mainPage" />
        </h:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have another problem with one of my pages which may be related. I have links that are dynamically generated with foreach statements that send GET requests, ie: orderID=1, orderID=2 etc.. and when I do a viewParam and set the value to CustomBuild.chosenOrder and then try to display that value in html, it shows up as 0 instead of what it should be. Is this a "scoping" issue?

Comment: I was able to solve the second issue by replacing the new namespace with the old sun name space. So changing xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" to xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" and the view param and get requests are now working. I tried doing the same thing to the xmlns:f on the original problem but it didnt help, data still not being set/saved.

Comment: What is the scope of your CustomBuild bean? @Richard Chase

Comment: Unrelated to question: you can move condition in `disabled` attribute like `<h:commandButton id="viewo" value="View Orders" action="vieworders" disabled="#{configs==0}" />` instead of write 8 lines with c:choose and c:when

Comment: Scope is Session Scoped which is what its supposed to be I think. I'm actually 100% sure on that since the documentation is confusing to me but basically I need everything to stay in scope while the browser is open, between pages. Kinda like how sessions work in PHP. Also on another note, thanks @VasilLukach for the tip about the disabled thing, very helpfull.

Comment: Another update: When I run the debugger, I can see that the getter and setter methods are being used and the value is being set to the correct one, however when the mainPage loads again (because the target of the save button is mainPage), it is still showing the old value and then when I click on edit/view personal, it also shows the old value. But looking at the variables in the debugger in netbeans and it does show the new value is saved. So then the question is, why is the webpage still showing the old value and not grabbing the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to try something. My plan was to run a save to database function when hitting the save button.

Makes sense right?

The function is below. Basically what is does is take the new data (which I know is being saved because I checked through the debugger) and save it back to the database. My plan was then to grab fresh data from the database when that mainPage and edit page were loaded.

This should definitely work.

However what I discovered was immediately after writing and testing the saveDetails function, the data in the inputFields is already being updated and shown. So this is the solution I guess but I have no idea WHY it suddenly works and didnt before since nothing in this function should affect the data saved in the bean.

Basically the next step would have been to write another function that grabs fresh data from the database and fill the bean data with it so that it would always show the most current data, but before I could even do that, the input fields started updating properly.

```
public String saveDetails() {
    try {
        int tempUserId = getUserid();
        String stringUserId = Integer.toString(tempUserId);
        String tempName = getName();
        String tempAddress = getAddress();
        String tempPhone = getPhone();
        String tempEmail = getEmail();

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TMA3C", "owner", "jsfdb");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "UPDATE APP.USERS SET FULLNAME = '" + tempName + "', ADDRESS = '" + tempAddress + "', PHONENUMBER = '" + tempPhone + "', "
                + "EMAIL = '" + tempEmail + "' WHERE USERID = " + stringUserId;
        System.out.println(query);
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CustomBuild.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CustomBuild.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return "mainPage";
}
```

Does anyone know WHY this suddenly solved this problem?